# environment returns dictionary in env.observation_space

Tags: python, dictionary, keras, artificial-intelligence, openai-gym

I have the following code. I have tried in multiple ways to somehow parse the data but failed.

```
env = MtEnv()

inputlist = []
balance = Input(shape=(1,), name="balance")
inputlist.append(balance)
equity = Input(shape=(1,), name="equity")
inputlist.append(equity)
margin = Input(shape=(1,), name="margin")
inputlist.append(margin)
features = Input(shape=(1,), name="features")
inputlist.append(features)
orders = Input(shape=(1,), name="orders")
inputlist.append(orders)
inputlist.sort(key=lambda inp: inp._keras_history.layer.name)

balance_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(balance)
equity_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(equity)
margin_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(margin)
features_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(features)
orders_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(orders)
combined = tensorflow.concat([balance_embedding, equity_embedding, margin_embedding, features_embedding, orders_embedding],1)
x= Dense(512, activation='relu')(combined)
x= Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x= Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(env.action_space.shape[0], activation="linear")(x)
data = env.observation_space
model = Model(inputs=inputlist, outputs=output)
#print(data.shape)
model.summary()

from keras.engine.base_layer import policy
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.policy import LinearAnnealedPolicy, EpsGreedyQPolicy
def build_agent(model,actions):
    policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), attr="eps", value_max=1., value_min=0.1, value_test=0.2, nb_steps=10000)
    memory= SequentialMemory(limit=2000, window_length=3)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model,memory=memory, policy=policy, enable_dueling_network=True,dueling_type='avg', nb_actions = actions, nb_steps_warmup=1000 )
    return dqn

dqn = build_agent(model, env.action_space.shape[0])

from keras.optimizers import Adam
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001))

dqn.fit(env,nb_steps=40000,visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

and the error I get is **ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 5 array(s), for inputs ['balance', 'equity', 'margin', 'features', 'orders'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[{'balance': array([0.]), 'equity': array([0.]), 'margin': array([0.]), 'features': array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0....**

I know the environment returns a Dict() which contains the inputs. I have been trying to somehow load the dictionary data inside 1 layer (or 5 layers if thats needed).

this environment can be ran without any problem using an A2C or PPO model from baseline3.

Comment: Can you show your `MtEnv` ?

Comment: here is the code https://pastebin.com/wntvE6ut

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example without all the other code? I think you can easily fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simpler:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf

balance = Input(shape=(1,), name="balance")
equity = Input(shape=(1,), name="equity")
margin = Input(shape=(1,), name="margin")
features = Input(shape=(1,), name="features")
orders = Input(shape=(1,), name="orders")

balance_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(balance)
equity_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(equity)
margin_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(margin)
features_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(features)
orders_embedding = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(orders)
combined = tf.concat([balance_embedding, equity_embedding, margin_embedding, features_embedding, orders_embedding],1)
x= Dense(512, activation='relu')(combined)
x= Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x= Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)

model = Model(inputs=[balance, equity, margin, features, orders], outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

Note: I've changed the number of nodes in your last Dense layer because I didn't knew the value of `env.action_space.shape[0]`.

The summary:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 balance (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 equity (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 margin (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 features (InputLayer)          [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 orders (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense_9 (Dense)                (None, 40)           80          ['balance[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense_10 (Dense)               (None, 40)           80          ['equity[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 dense_11 (Dense)               (None, 40)           80          ['margin[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 dense_12 (Dense)               (None, 40)           80          ['features[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 dense_13 (Dense)               (None, 40)           80          ['orders[0][0]']                 
  

                                                                                            
 tf.concat_1 (TFOpLambda)       (None, 200)          0           ['dense_9[0][0]',                
                                                                  'dense_10[0][0]',               
                                                                  'dense_11[0][0]',               
                                                                  'dense_12[0][0]',               
                                                                  'dense_13[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 dense_14 (Dense)               (None, 512)          102912      ['tf.concat_1[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dense_15 (Dense)               (None, 256)          131328      ['dense_14[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 dense_16 (Dense)               (None, 128)          32896       ['dense_15[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 dense_17 (Dense)               (None, 1)            129         ['dense_16[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 267,665
Trainable params: 267,665
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn't work. Yes the model compiles correctly but once it is ran on the environment it gives the same error. The only difference is that you don't use a list for the inputs but add them manually.